# JSPX tags doesn't work with Wildfly CR1

Tags: jboss, jspx, wildfly

I've posted this question in jboss forums, but I get no answers.

I think that I miss anything, but I can't know what I miss.

When I migrate an existing app from JBoss AS 7.1 to Wildfly 8CR1, I got the error bellow.

When the application starts, the first page that I access are displayed fine. But the second page that I access, the error occurs. I think that Wildfly compiles my default.tagx and the first page that includes the tag works fine. But any another page can't get the compiled tagx.

My code is like:

default.tagx

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="2.2">

    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="HTML" 
doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    some code
    <jsp:doBody />
    more code
</jsp:root>
```

And all pages uses:

```
<tags:default xmlns:tags="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags" 
xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
    my code here
</tags:default>
```

And the error is:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.jsp.tag.web.default_tagx cannot be cast to org.apache.jsp.tag.web.default_tagx
```

Comment: How does you web.xml look like and what is the contents of your WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is a Wildfly 8.0.0-CR1 issue, because updating to 8.1-Final, everything works fine. So if anyone have this problem, updating will fix.